# How to create a POST request properly using ServiceStack for C#

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, servicestack

I have an API which contains the following bit. It is supposed to receive a `Person` object.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(Person person)
{
    ...
}
```

I also have a consumer for this API:

```
IRestClient restClient = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:12345")
{
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
};

var person= new Person
{
    Name = "B1"
};

restClient.Post<HttpWebResponse>("my-route", person);
```

When I post the `person`, I can trace until the last line, client-side, that everything seems to be in order.

I catch the request successfully in the API - But the `Name` of the `person` is now `null`, along with any other properties he might have had.

What could I be doing wrong here? Where could I look for hints?

Comment: Try using the `[FromBody]` parameter binding attribute `public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Person person)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `[FromBody]` parameter binding attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Person person) {
    //...
}
```

Also make sure the model's exposed members are public properties and not fields.

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //...other public properties
}
```

Comment: Spot on. `[FromBody]` made all the difference. I also found out why. I failed to mention that my API is an ASP.NET Core project, which makes a difference. In normal ASP.NET, complex types such as `Person` is assumed to come from the body by default. This is not the case for ASP.NET Core, hence my mistake. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!